# How to power a peltier element with something portable?

Tags: peltier, thermocouple

Actually the question is bigger. I will start from the beginning.

I want to make a surface, which I can carry in a bag with me, and when I turn it on I want a given part of the surface to become very hot (around 60 degrees celsius) very quick and another side, which becomes cold (around -10 degrees celsius) very quick.

I have stopped at a Peltier - **TEC1-12706** for this project.

I see that a lot of people use 12V 5A power supplies, but almost everyone connects them directly to a power outlet at home. I want something to provide this power that I can carry around.

Note: It will not be used to operate some type of machine. I need to power it up only for a few seconds maybe a minute. I just really need the desired temperatures only for a few seconds.

Also, I am a big newbie in this branch, so please guide me on how to make it as practical as possible.
I mean - easy tools for connecting the Peltier to the power supply, what is best to use for turning it on and off etc. I do not know the names of many of the basic parts used, so you need to explain it as you would to an 8-year-old.

**To summarize:**
I need a device, which will be sitting turned off. I want to turn it on and have a 60 degrees surface in a matter of seconds and a -10 surface also in a matter of seconds.
Then it can turn off.

Comment: Welcome! A suitable battery pack with a DC/DC converter to supply the voltage and current needed?

Comment: It is a challenge to get 30 C difference between the two sides.  70 C delta will be incredibly challenging, if not impossible.  The two sides are not very well thermally isolated from eachother.  The figures in the datasheet are...optimistic.

Comment: @evildemonic I do not need those temperatures on the same peltier. I will use two different. I don't care about the difference, I just need the temperature on one side.

Comment: @AngelMiladinov Ok, this could work then.  Use current-controlled source (rather than voltage or PWM).

Answer (score 0):

I don't think it will matter whether you use voltage or current regulation as you will end up with the same result. The peltier will use the voltage that the current allows and vice versa. I could be wrong though. But I'm fairly sure you will get the same watt loading, either way.